# How can I iterate elastic search Bucket using c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Currently, I am using NEST API to get data from elastic search and I am trying Term Aggregation and the response was valid but I was unable to access the data in the bucket.
Basically, unable to iterate through the fields in the bucket.

Here is my code to do the term aggregation

```
       var result = client.Search<GoodDataAttribute>(s => s 
                .Aggregations(a => a 
                .Terms("Resourcegroup", st => st 
                .Field(o => o.ResourceGroup) 
                .Size(16) 
                .ExecutionHint(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.Map) 
                ))); 
            var result1 = result.Documents; 
            Console.WriteLine(result1); 
            foreach (var result2 in result.Documents) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(result2.ResourceGroup); 
            } 
            var resultGroups = result.Aggregations; 
            Console.WriteLine(resultGroups.Count); 
            foreach (var resultGroup in resultGroups.Values) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(resultGroup.ToString()); 
            }
```

Comment: Does it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666667/elasticsearch-date-histogram-report-with-terms-aggregation/30667181#30667181 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Aggs` property of the result. According to the documentation:

> The result of the aggregations are accessed from the Aggs property of the response using the key that was specified on the request...

In your example this would be `Resourcegroup`. I have used this in solutions and it  works as expected. Your code should look something like

```
var agg = results.Aggs.Terms("Resourcegroup");
if (agg!= null && agg.Items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var resourceGroupAgg in agg.Items)
    {
        // do something with the aggregations
        // the term is accessed using the Key property
        var term = resourceGroupAgg.Key;
        // the count is accessed through the DocCount property
        var count = resourceGroupAgg.Count;
    }
}
```

There is more detail in the [documentation](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/handling.html).

Hope this helps .

Comment: Just thought I'd add that to get your items, you now need to refer to agg.Buckets .  This answer helped me get there. thank you.